# How to render Angular component as control

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-components

I'm trying to include child component as [leaflet control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html) in parent component using `innerHTML` property;

```
legend.innerHTML = '<app-legend></app-legend>';
```

but it won't render, although definition exists
[image]

Does anyone know is there a way to render component using `innerHTML` or I should try with directive?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-custom-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at **componentFactoryResolvers** in this [link](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/)

There you can dynamically create components and bind them to the view

Comment: I'm trying to implement using componentFacrotyResolvers, but I'm stuck with `Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined` error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-custom-control-ypdffq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fleaflet%2Fleaflet.component.ts

Comment: Use reference in html.                                                                                 
  <div #parent id="leaflet-map">
 </div>  and write code in ngAfterViewInit() as viewChild variables will set only after view is initialized